# Calculate visibility of normal vectors

Tags: c++, vector, linear-algebra

I have a mesh shown in the picture below. Each segment of the mesh has a positive (**np**) and negative normal (**nn**). Each pair of normals belongs to a segment from the mesh.
[image]

The red dot in the middle is my observation point. I need to find out which normals are visible to this observation point.

The method I have followed so far is to to calculate a normal vector from the observation point to the middle of the each mesh segment (**ob_i**). I then do the dot product on the **ob_i** and **np** or **nn**. The result of this is either greater than zero or less than. If it is less than the vector is facing the other way and can be regarded as hidden from the observation point.

With this method I get the following result:
[image]

Heres how I calculate the dot product and check for visibility:

```
vector<vector<int>> calculateShadowingMatrix(vector<point> observationNormals, vector<vector<point>> normals){
vector<vector<int>> shadowMatrix;

for(unsigned ii = 0; ii < normals.size(); ii++){
    vector<int> visibilty;

    for(unsigned jj = 0; jj < normals[ii].size(); jj++) {

        double dot = dotProduct(observationNormals[ii], normals[ii][jj]);

        if (dot <= 0.0) {
            visibilty.push_back(1);
        } else {
            visibilty.push_back(0);
        }

    }
    shadowMatrix.push_back(visibilty);
}

return shadowMatrix;
}

double dotProduct(point _u, point _v){
    return _u.getX()*_v.getX() - _u.getY()*_v.getY();
}
```

I am trying to get all of the normal vectors which are facing the observation point to be present and zero out the ones which are facing outwards. I get errors, as can be seen in the second image, some of the vector are facing the wrong direction.

Final result should look as follows:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: To have all of the normal vector arrows pointing towards the observation point. In the first picture, I want the red arrow present on the right structure and blue arrow present on the left structure.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Update this in the question to help others help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dot product calculation is wrong.  It should be X * X + Y * Y.